# Using waveshare LCD and SPI1 for LEDs

Tags: spi, device-tree

My problem is that I cant get SPI1 and the LCD screen to work at the same time.

Only SPI1 with the `spi1-1cs` overlay worked and only the `waveshare35a` overlay working, I tried to make my own overlay and didn't worked, I don't even get the `spydev1.0` to show up together with my LCD screen.

I have a Pi3 with Jessi and a Waveshare 3.5" LCD.

Comment: What sort of LEDs?  Why do they need to be connected via SPI?  Why not use the auxiliary SPI device?

Comment: WS2801 LEDs, and i need the spi to controll each LED 
individually, here is a link (german)(https://tutorials-raspberrypi.de/raspberry-pi-ws2801-rgb-led-streifen-anschliessen-steuern/)

Comment: For future reference APA102 based LED strips are much easier to control.  They don't force you to use SPI or PWM/PCM hardware to drive them on the Pi.

Comment: i must correct you, you need also a spi for the clock and a data line, so its pretty much the same, without spi you can't controll the LEDs individually.

Comment: You do not need SPI to control an APA102 based LED strip.  Any pair of GPIO can be used.

Comment: (http://www.elec-tron.org/?page_id=1296) how would it work without SPI? Do you simulate the clock and the data line??

Comment: The WS2801 and APA102 are not SPI chips.  They just accept signals which can be driven by SPI hardware.  You write the value to send to the data GPIO (high, low).  You toggle the clock GPIO to send that data.  You repeat.  Any pair of GPIO will work.

Comment: Ok, should work like that, but there is a second SPI in the PI and i would like to use it, so i can use the adafruit framework, that would make it much easier to make fancy stuff